# How to find the last mdified subfolder in a folder using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a folder which has certain subfolders..Now I want to find the subfolder which modified last ..Is there any function that I can use for this.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objRootFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FilePath)
Set colSubfolders = objRootFolder.SubFolders

For Each objFolder in colSubfolders


      WScript.Echo objFolder


      IF(objFolder.SubFolders.Count > 1 ) THEN

        For Each fldr In objFolder.SubFolders     


        END If         

        NEXT
            WScript.Echo LastFolder
        WScript.Echo LastDate
        END IF
        NEXT



Set FSO= Nothing
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 set lastFolder = nothing
 lastTime = CDate("1900-01-01")

 For Each fldr In objFolder.SubFolders     
   If fldr.DateLastModified > lastTime Then
       Set lastFolder = fldr
       lastTime = fldr.DateLastModified
   End If
 Next 

 WScript.Echo lastFolder.Name
```